# What free tools for managing java keystores and security certificates available around

Tags: java, security, certificate, keystore

What free tools for managing java keystores and security certificates are available around?

Comment: Asking for "best" is usually not a good question, **especially** when you don't tell us what criteria you want to judge. My suggestion would be: `keytool` is best, because it comes with the JDK!

Comment: funny but the only one that worked for me was IBM KeyMan. It can be downloaded with IBM JDK or as a separate package, from [IBM website](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=AW-028&S_PKG=028&lang=en_US&cp=UTF-8) (registration required)

Comment: (correction - registration not required)

Comment: http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/index.php may help !

Comment: Key Store Explorer is OK, but not useful for Android development due to its lack of support for aliases or layered passwords.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/). At least, it has a GUI :-)

**EDIT** (sept. 2020) [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) is in fact more feature complete and more user-friendly.

Comment: KeyStore explorer looks good too. It's free but I'm not sure if it's open source - anyway, it works well and runs on all the major platforms.
http://www.lazgosoftware.com/kse/index.html

Comment: KeyStore helped me. Great tool.

Comment: KeyStore Explorer is open source since 2013-10-19. http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: KeyStore Explorer's new location is in github here: https://github.com/kaikramer/keystore-explorer and its official website (referenced in the README of the github source code) is http://www.keystore-explorer.org/ - This will avoid potential malware injected by sourceforge.

Comment: keystore explorer won't work on Java 11.

Answer (score 5):

One more alternative is [**openssl**](http://www.openssl.org/).

*From self experience:*
**keytool**. It worth to keep in mind that it handles only public keys. Do not waste few days to figure it out ;)
[**Portacle**](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) is able to manage private keys. Are there any advantages to use command line tool if you are not trying to use it in some automation scripts than to use user friendly GUI tool?
[**OpenSSL**](http://www.openssl.org/) appeared to be most feature rich as for me. It is able to handle not simplest situation like to create CA and sign some self signed sertificate, i.e. to create sertification chain. [Creating Certificate Authorities and self-signed SSL certificates](http://web.archive.org/web/20120509214649/http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html)

Comment: But the question was about handling *java* keystores, which openssl doesn't do !

Answer (score 3):

**keytool**

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the **keytool** command-line tool that comes with the JDK. It seems complicated in the beginning, but once you get used to it, it's pretty efficient for managing your keystores, etc.

If you really dislike command-line, though, I guess it's not for you.

Comment: Cons: cannot manage private keys in any way, cannot import CA reply without checking certificate chain.

Working with keytool proved to be a PITA - all automation scripts are a huge back and forth between keytool and openssl, because both lack essential features.